# Entity Framework se demora mucho en cargar la primera consulta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, iis

estoy trabajando con ASP MVC 5 y Entity Framework 6 y hace un tiempo el desarrollo de la aplicación terminó y esta se implementó en el servidor IIS de la empresa donde trabajo.

La aplicación funciona sin problemas, los tiempos de carga son correctos a excepción de la **primera** query de Entity Framework, tras realizarse esta primera consulta, luego todos los tiempos de carga son normales.

El ingresar por **primera vez** a una vista que realice alguna consulta, toma un estimado de *8 segundos*, luego carga de manera veloz (menos de *1 segundo*) hasta que el sitio está inactivo durante un lapso prolongado de tiempo, tras lo que nuevamente vuelve a tomar esos *8 segundos* la primer query

Cabe aclarar, que esto solo sucede dentro de IIS, al utilizar Visual Studio esto no me sucedía

¿A qué se debe esto?

*No se si falta algún dato que pueda ser de utilidad, dado el caso, ¡por favor avisarme en los comentarios!*

**Edit con algo de información adicional:**

Uso Entity Framework versión 6.2 Code First.

Mi Clase `DbContext` se ve de la siguiente manera (aclaro que deje sólo una entidad para no tener tanto código irrelevante)

```
public partial class DBTrafosContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public DBTrafosContext() : base("name=DBTrafosPROD"){}
    public virtual DbSet<Transformador> Transformador { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new NonPublicColumnAttributeConvention());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

y al hacer uso de la clase, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
using(var db = new DBTrafosContext())
{
    var Lista = db.Transformador.Where(c => c.Potencia > 300).ToList();
}
```

Aclaro que en la base de datos manejo y manejaré una cantidad de registros baja, dudo tener más de 1000 registros teniendo en cuenta todas las tablas

Edit 2: Agrego la configuración avanzada de Application Pool.

*General*

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|             Propiedad             |   Valor    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| Habilitar aplicaciones de 32 bits | False      |
| Longitud de Cola                  | 1000       |
| Modo de canalización administrada | Integrated |
| Versión de .NET CLR               | v4.0       |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

*CPU*

```
+------------------------------------+----------+
|             Propiedad              |  Valor   |
+------------------------------------+----------+
| Acción de límite                   | NoAction |
| Afinidad del procesador habilitada | False    |
| Intervalo límite (minutos)         | 5        |
| Límite (porcentaje)                | 0        |
+------------------------------------+----------+
```

*Modelo de proceso*

```
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|                   Propiedad                    |          Valor          |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Acción de tiempo de Inactividad                | Terminate               |
| Carga de perfil de usuario                     | False                   |
| Identidad                                      | ApplicationPoolIdentity |
| Límite de tiempo de cierre (segundos)          | 90                      |
| Límite de tiempo de inicio (segundos)          | 90                      |
| Máximo de procesos de trabajo                  | 1                       |
| Tiempo de inactividad (minutos)                | 20                      |
| Tiempo máximo de respuesta de ping (segundos)  | 90                      |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: que version estas utilizando EF 7 tiene buen performance en la primer consulta y como estas declarando la carga de tu base de datos , es first code? como puedes ver debes remormular tu pregunta agregando un poco de codigo

Comment: @MiguelZarate gracias por el comentario, ahí agregue la información que me dijiste!

Comment: si te puedes manejar en ingles aqui hay un buen articulo: https://www.fusonic.net/developers/2014/07/09/3-steps-for-fast-entity-framework-6-1-code-first-startup-performance/

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Hola, gracias! leí ese artículo esta mañana y no entendí del todo como funciona lo que respecta al caché por eso no logre implementarlo

Comment: puedes agregar la configuracion de tu pool de IIS para tu aplicacion? application pool -> advanced settings

Comment: @MiguelZarate ahí añadí la información, si falta algo no dudes decirme :D

Comment: Leete este post sobre las [Buenas prácticas para contextos de tiempo de vida cortos](https://geeks.ms/quintas/2008/02/14/ado-net-entity-framework-buenas-prcticas-para-contextos-de-tiempo-de-vida-cortos/). No tiene mucha relacion con tu pregunta, pero quizas algunas de las configuraciones o practicas que ponen de ejemplo te guie a una solucion.

Comment: Y al usar asyn await obtienes el mismo resultado? `var Lista = await db.Transformador.Where(c => c.Potencia > 300).ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que describes es normal es asi como funciona, el primer acceso es penalizado ya que requiere parsear y validar el contexto, una vez que esta en memoria ya no requiere cargarse nuevamente, solo ejecuta la operacion.

Por lo general ante inactividad los thread del `IIS` seguramente se reciclen por eso es que nuevamente se comporta como el primer acceso.

Pero existe una opcion de configuracion que podria ayudar

[Speeding up your application with the IIS Auto-Start feature](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/)

Se trata del `Start Mode` del `Application Pool` que usa el web site

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con esta deberia resolverse el problema que planteas

Comment: Hola Leandro, gracias por la respuesta, pero actualmente lo tengo configurado de esa manera, mi problema sólo se da cuando se ejecuta una acción de **Entity Framework**, cuando se ejecuta cualquier vista que no tenga acceso a la bd es casi instantáneo

Comment: Es que es jutamente lo que comento EF requiere un primer parse y validacion del mapping cuando carga, por eso se ve afectado el primer acceso. No se como implementas pero si realizas con alguna tools de integracion continua podrias poner un paso al final que realice ese primer acceso para que no se vea penalizado el usuario

Comment: No uso ninguna herramienta de integración continua, ¿podrías orientarme acerca del tema para intentar implementar una que haga el primer acceso como planteas?

Comment: podrias utilizar Jenkins  https://www.javiergarzas.com/2014/05/jenkins-en-menos-de-10-min.html, esta automatiza la operacion de deploy en los ambientes y permite realizar tareas, una de estas tareas del final podria ser acceder al sitio, asi se ve penalizado ese primer acceso la tool de integracion y no el usuario

Answer (score 0):

Si aplicas lo de Leonardo lo siguiente no es necesario, pero en caso que no quieras que tu aplicacion consuma recursos sin ser utilizado,
 agrega EF al jit cada vez que ejecutas la aplicacion dependiendo de tu version de framework  digamos que tu carpeta encuentras la version 7 ejecuta:

%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen install EntityFramework.dll

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, disculpame, pero no entiendo que debo hacer con la información que me das

Comment: ngen  te ayuda a instalar librerias en jit, en caso de EF este no viene por default en el .net framework cada vez que ejecutas una aplicacion con EF esta agrega la libreria a JIT cuando tu aplicacion se detiene se libera del JIT, esto puede ser Una causa de tu lento perfomance .

Comment: Al querer ejecutar el comando recibo el mensaje `Error: The specified file or directory "EntityFramework.dll" is invalid`, ¿qué puedo hacer?

Comment: disculpa olvide mensiona cuando instalas un elemento debes especificar la ruta en este caso busca donde esta la dll, ejemplo la dll esta en C:\Codigo\Bin y  tu  instalacion seria -->...install C:\Codigo\Bin\EntityFramework.dll

Comment: y en qué ruta debería instalarlo? en `....\Framework\v4.0.30319`?

Comment: abre tu folder explorer y busca cual es la mayor version que tienes y abre ese folder en tu ruta copia, y pega en el promt de tu consola , C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ (tuversion)

Comment: Ahí logre hacerlo, pero el tiempo de carga sigue siendo prácticamente el mismo :(

Comment: la clasica configuracion dentro de  tu inicio de clase establece las propiedades es public DBTrafosContext() : base("name=DBTrafosPROD"){ this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91010/discussion-between-miguel-zarate-and-juan-salvador-portugal).